# Install Moodle with nginx and $CFG->slasharguments = false;

Tags: php, moodle

I use Nginx and when I install moodle, rewrite URL don't work.
When I set `$CFG->slasharguments = false;` in config.php, site work well but URL of the site don't rewrite.

Can I config rewrite for Moodle with Nginx ? Thank you

Sorry for bad English :(

Comment: You should post your attempts to solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.moodle.org/31/en/Nginx#Nginx shows an example of how to configure Moodle with NGINX supporting slash arguments. It is best to leave slash arguments enabled as it [will be required](https://docs.moodle.org/31/en/Using_slash_arguments#Slash_arguments_environment_check) in future versions of Moodle.

Answer (score 0):

In Moodle 3.4 with IIS server, SCROM course (`mod/scorm/player.php`) page returns a

```
WARNING: slash arguments is disabled on this site and objects may not function as expected
```

I put the following line in `moodle/config.php` file,

```
$CFG->slasharguments = true;
IIS Restart
```

Issue has been fixed.

Thanks,

Prakash M